# Android App crashes when file is created

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently making an android game.
Now I wanted to save the user's highscore. I decided to use files in order to save that data.
The app worked perfectly fine before but now it crashes every time the setHighscore() or the getHighscore() method is called. Every piece of code that might be needed for you in order to review the problem is attached. I'm thankful for every answer!

App.class:

```
public class App extends Application {

private static Context context;
private static File directory;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();
    directory = getFilesDir();
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return  context;
}

public static File getDirectory() { return directory; }

}
```

Highscore.class:

```
public class Highscore {

public static void setHighscore(int highscore) throws IOException {
    FileUtils.saveData(FILE_HIGHSCORE(), highscore+"");
}

public static int getHighscore(int highscore) throws IOException {
    return Integer.parseInt(getData(FILE_HIGHSCORE()));
}

private static File FILE_HIGHSCORE() throws IOException {
    return getFile("PLAYER_HIGHSCORE.txt", DIRECTORY_MAIN);
}

}
```

**If you want to take a look at another class/method just tell me!**

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I test the app with my own device (htc one(m7) mini), debugging the app in Android Studio never really worked for me (takes much time to load,..)

Comment: share the error message too.

Comment: It's just 'Unfortunately [app] has stopped'

Comment: post your main activity please